# Need help converting py to js

Tags: javascript, python

In python, I can join elements in an array by doing:

```
print(a)
b=' '.join(a)
print(b)
```

and I get:

```
['hhhh', 'hhhh']
hhhh hhhh
```

How would I do this in js?

Comment: `b = a.join(' ')` See the [manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same thing, man! 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

`b = a.join(' ')`

Answer (score 0):

If you want join arrays:

```
let a ='hhhh';
let b = [].concat(a);
b.concat(a)
```

If you want to join string

```
let sth  = "a" + " b";
```